Blazor for loop returns index out of error
I have to list items and add the input number for each item in list. But below code returns ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
@for (int i = 0; i < class1s.Count; i++)
{

<InputNumber @bind-Value="@class1s[i].Value" class="form-control"></InputNumber>
      
}

@code {
List class1s;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    class1s = new List<class1>();
    class1s.Add(new class1() { Value = 1, Index = 1 });
    class1s.Add(new class1() { Value = 2, Index = 2 });
    class1s.Add(new class1() { Value = 3, Index = 3 });
    class1s.Add(new class1() { Value = 4, Index = 4 });
    class1s.Add(new class1() { Value = 5, Index = 5 });
}


public class class1
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

}
the error returns is
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
